# MySQL Query error when run within Python but not when run directly

Tags: python, mysql, django

I am passing `'2012-09-10 00:00:00-05:00'` to a MySQL query. This value is retrieved using the [pytz module](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/) for Python.

```
import pytz
class MyClass():
    def __init____(self):
        self.tz = pytz.timezone(settings.TIME_ZONE)
        todaystart = self.tz.localize(datetime.now(self.tz).replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0, tzinfo=None), is_dst=None).astimezone(self.tz)
```

The MySQL query is this, after `todaystart` has been substituted in:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE created > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE('2012-09-10 00:00:00-05:00','%Y-%m-%d %k:%i:%s') - INTERVAL 1 DAY);
```

If I execute this query directly, it returns data as expected. If I put this query into code it gives this error: `Warning: Truncated incorrect datetime value: '2012-09-09 00:00:00-05:00'`

The code I am using is this (within Django):

```
query = """SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE created > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE('2012-09-10 00:00:00-05:00','%Y-%m-%d %k:%i:%s') - INTERVAL 1 DAY);"""
myCursor = connections[system_db].cursor()
results = myCursor.execute(query)    # Dies on this statement
resultcount = results.fetchall()
```

I didn't see an offset [format](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) string in the MySQL docs for str_to_date. I would prefer to keep that offset, as the data is returned for a 3rd party system and by keeping it in place I don't have to do any logic between that return and executing the query with the returned date. However, I don't think it has to do with the offset since it works if I run it directly.

What have I done incorrectly that would cause this `Warning` to appear when Python runs the query against MySQL?

Comment: mysql's date/time format doesn't include timezones. You haven't included that `-05:00` in the format string in str_to_date, so you get a warning that the string is truncated. warnings aren't an error, so it should work fine in your clients.

Comment: In order to keep the timezone information in MySQL, convert all datetime objects to UTC before storing them. The mysql command line client doesn't show warnings directly when they occur, it merely hints them (`Query OK, 1 row affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)`). Other clients might hide them completely.

Comment: and this should remove the time zone info: dt = dt_tz.replace(tzinfo=None)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Marc B had it right.

When executed directly, you are getting the warnings, but probably not noticing:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE created > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE('2012-09-10 00:00:00-05:00','%Y-%m-%d %k:%i:%s') - INTERVAL 1 DAY);
Empty set, 3 warnings (0.00 sec)

mysql> show warnings;
+---------+------+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                                              |
+---------+------+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect datetime value: '2012-09-10 00:00:00-05:00'      |
| Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect datetime value: '2012-09-10 00:00:00-05:00'      |
| Warning | 1292 | Incorrect datetime value: '1347148800' for column 'created' at row 1 |
+---------+------+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```